# ajax field insert without loading second page bug

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, vbscript

So I went through this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/ and instead of using php I created my own classic asp page, but one thing is bugging me when trying to put spaces in the input boxes they do not show up for example if I put bill gates in the name field it shows up as billgates

any ideas

```
$(".btn22").bind("click", function() {
var name = $("input#yourname").val();
if (name === "") {
$("input#yourname").focus();
   return false;
}
var email = $("input#youremail").val();
if (email === "") {
$("input#youremail").focus();
    return false;
}
var message5 = $("#limitedtextarea").text();
if (message5 === "") {
    $("#limitedtextarea").focus();
    return false;
}
var sku5 = $("#sku5").val();
var dataString = 'yourname='+ name + '&youremail=' + email + '&message=' + message5 + '&sku5=' + sku5;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actions/newreview.asp",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<br><br><p class='big red'>Thanks for the review.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
        $('#message');
    });
}
});
return false;
});
});
'asp looks like this

name = request.form("yourname")
email = request.form("youremail")
sku = request.form("sku5")
comment = request.form("message")
then inserts names into a database, but it has already gotten rid of the spaces before this point
```

Comment: Nothing mentioned in that tutorial could cause that as far as I can see, could you please share some actual code/example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @DavidMulder reposted with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out just added name = escape(name) add the %20 in and then take it out to add spaces in my asp code

thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to post your markup here for us to tell what's going on for sure, but have you set the input type to type='text'?

Comment: yup sure have, I know it is not the form that is having problems

Comment: @SheikhHeera I can't comment on original questions because I don't have enough reputation. :/

Comment: Hopefully they are as reasonable and friendly as you, until I have enough rep! :) I'll try to refrain from answering in comment-like fashion.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are doing your own encoding of the form data. Not sure if that's the problem but it could be. jQuery includes a utility that does this for you.

```
dataString = $("#JqAjaxForm").serialize();
```

reference: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Some other comments:

- you may wish to produce a javascript object, rather than just use form encoding. In this case jQuery will serialize it into json, if you use `dataType:json` on the `post()` method.
- use Javascript in your classic ASP page.  It may make things a little simpler for you, to use the same language on client (browser) and server.